# How to make context menu disappear?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Let's use 'Ask Question' button of http://www.stackoverflow.com for this question.

Suppose, I perform context click on 'Ask Question' button, it'll result into appearance of context menu.

```
btn_ask_question = driver.find_element(:css, '.nav.askquestion li')
driver.action.context_click(btn_ask_question).perform
```

Now, I want context menu to disappear. How can I achieve this using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby? release method doesn't work.

Following is context menu image:

[image: context_menu]

Comment: which one is context menu? can you give the screen shot image?

Comment: Hey, downvoter, you should explain why question doesn't show any research. It's not good in this community to downvote without explaining.

Comment: Babai, I added image. Can you help me now?

Comment: I think you need to click outside anywhere of that page,which in turn disappear the context menu..

Comment: Yes Babai, I was thinking the same. But I'm looking if there is api for making context menu to disappear. Otherwise, I'll use 'click outside anywhere of that page' method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything built-in for handling system level context menu.

The easiest you might try is to find the body element, click the body.

```
driver.find_element(:css, 'body').click
```

Comment: I also think the same. Thanks user1177636!